# How to get all the parameters of this WSDL document web methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, wsdl

I am working on a project where in which the requirement is to get all the web methods of the WSDL document including its parameters to get/send the data from/to web services.
I request to suggest solution for that .

Answer (score 0):

You can create a web service proxy class from a command prompt using **Wsdl.exe**

Refer [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2s8y7bs%28VS.71%29.aspx)